# Xubuntu 19.10 with ZSH hangs after login in tty

Tags: xubuntu, login, tty, zsh

I have oh-my-zsh installed on my Xubuntu 19.10. Sometimes, as (X)ubuntu usually does, it freezes together with the whole X server.
Therefore I wanted to switch to tty1. Once I provided my credentials, the tty is stuck.

I tried to reproduce the issue without having a frozen X server on tty7, so I logged into tty1 again and then back to tty7. Looking at the processes I see zsh using a whole core. If I kill the process, the login sequence in the tty1 is killed and I would need to login again.

Watching auth.log the user get logged in as well, so that's another reason why it could be ZSH:

```
Apr 23 21:52:29 laptop systemd[1]: Started Session 8 of user userr.
Apr 23 21:52:40 laptop systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Succeeded.
Apr 23 21:52:40 laptop systemd[1]: session-8.scope: Succeeded.
Apr 23 21:52:40 laptop systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.
Apr 23 21:52:40 laptop systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Apr 23 21:52:40 laptop systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Apr 23 21:52:40 laptop systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
```

Please let me know if you need any more logs :)